# Load DialogFragment from another dialogframent with proper transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmenttransaction, dialogfragment

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

I want to load DialogFragment from another dialogframent with proper transition like the ones implemented by Google Drive and Facebook.

I want to achieve something similar to this one.
I have given the example of Google Drive.
Here is the scenario what happens in Drive.

If you want to upload a file to drive it will open screen 1. And when you tap on any folder(Android Basic) it will load screen 2. Screen 2 will not be loaded on top of Screen 1. It appears as if it completely occupies spaces of Screen 1.

Similar thing happens when in Facebook mobile app as well. When you click on number of likes/comment button, it will show likes at the top and comments just below to that. Now when you click on the likes, it will load another screen which will give the list of all the persons who liked the post.

Here is what I want to achieve.

Currently I am opening a dialog fragment from a fragment.
Fragment 1 -> DialogFragment 1.

Consider that dialog 1 has a button which will display License Agreement. So when the user clicks on that button I want to load Fragment 2.
So DialogFragment1 -> DialogFrgment 2.

This is happening fine. But when I load the dialog fragment it is shown on top of the DialogFragment 1. I do not want this. I want the left to right kind of animation which is possible with the normal fragments using setTranstition methods and is being implemented in Drive and Facebook apps beautifully.

How can I load the second dialogFragment in this way?